# giving device connected via eth0 an ip on hostapd network

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, dhcp

I have a Raspberry Pi with 2 wifi adapters and 2 ethernet ports on it. There are two devices connected via ethernet to the Pi. I've used isc-dhcp-server to give both of them separate subnets and IP addresses (172.20.20.2 and 172.20.30.2). I'm also using hostapd and isc-dhcp-server to broadcast the wifi network I'm connected to (I'm connected using the first wifi adapter) over my second wifi adapter.

However, only the Pi can access the two devices connected over ethernet right now. If I `ping 172.20.20.2`, it works, but I obviously can't ping that IP from another device which is connected to the hotspot my Pi is broadcasting. My goal is to give the two devices connected over ethernet IP addresses on the hotspot network. Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing it?